# Hadoop: Measuring shuffle time from JAVA

Tags: java, hadoop

Is there a way to get the shuffle time required from each reduce task from the client side using the Hadoop API (Hadoop 1.2.1). I can get the execution time of the reduce tasks from the JobClient using the getReduceTaskReports(JobID jobID) method, but I wonder is there a way to get the percentage that corresponds to the shuffle time. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO Niko! Maybe these methods will be useful (`getShuffleFinishTime` and `getStartTime`) https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskStatus.html.

Comment: I found this class TaskStatus but I am not sure how can I retrieve it when a job has finished.

Comment: Can anyone provide more details on how to access the TaskStatus class after the job has finished. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was to use Apache Rumen (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/rumen.html). This framework enables you to retrieve job history logs in a JSON format, with simple JSON parsing I was able to retrieve the information I needed.